# Truncate links with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I truncate links through the Html Helper in CakePHP?

the book only truncates text strings, but how the truncate a link like this?

```
$this->Html->link('This is a very long link that needs to be truncated', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine usage with the [TextHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1469/Text)::[truncate](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1469/Text#truncate-1625) method. Example:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Text->truncate('This is a very long link that needs to be truncated'),
    '/pages/home',
    array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank')
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I got it to work, the only thing thing I added was the truncate value <?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Text->truncate('This is a very long link that needs to be truncated', 10),
    '/pages/home',
    array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank')
);
?>